# A bot that deletes a message from a user if it contains a specific word

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot that automatically deletes a message when a user uses a specific word in their message. The code itself doesn't show any problems but when I test it it doesn't do anything.

```
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: Events.AutoDelete,
  async execute(_delete) {
    if (message.author.id === 'userId' && message.content.includes('word')) {
      return message.delete();
    }
  },
};
```

I just started coding so I don't know what to look out for so any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to use `message.content`, not `_delete`. `_delete` is just the name of the function argument, not the actual message content.

Comment: replace `execute(_delete)` with `execute(message)`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such event called `AutoDelete`. Consider using the **`messageCreate`** event and also fix your name conventions.

```js
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: Events.MessageCreate,
  async execute(message) {
    if (message.author.id === 'userId' && message.content.toLowerCase().includes('word')) {
      return message.delete();
    }
  },
};
```